# RESTFUL API with AWS S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, api, spring-boot, amazon-s3

So my "tech lead" wanted my team to create a REST API with SpringBoot using AWS DynamoDB as the database and we were successful to implement that. But, now he wants to replace AWS DynamoDB with AWS S3, which to me does not make sense. How would that work? Save the API calls as a text file then store it in S3? How the hell am I supposed to do that? Say I can do a POST request and there are 5 of them in a file in S3, next how do I delete or update just say 2 records there? Does anyone have any experience that can shed a light in here? Also before you ask, "WhY dOnT u AsK teCh lEaD?" we did and he said "figure it out on ur own" same answer when we asked how to use DynamoDB

Comment: you cannot replace `DynamoDB` with `S3`. It doesn't make sense. May be your tech lead should be replaced.

Comment: You can use AWS Athena and integrate with APIgetway and Lambda to give rest call , No SpringBoot  required here .

Comment: @Asdfg of course you can't *fully* replace DynamoDB with S3, but you absolutely can use S3 in some applications as a simple, eventually-consistent, NoSQL database, with a single primary key or even a pseudo-partition key + sort key concatenated with a delimiter as the object key (so you can either "query" with the full key or "scan" the sort keys within a "partition" using S3's ListObjects API)... and store the attributes as JSON in the object body... and the operational cost difference can even be pretty compelling in some cases.

Comment: @vaquarkhan do you have a video or article guide on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use AWS API gateway (which enables you to create REST APIs) integration with S3 for something like this.  Or roll your own API that uses the AWS SDK to make requests to S3.  S3 is an object store and not a database, you can use REST APIs to store individual objects, so rather than 1 "file" as you put it with 2 records in there, you have an object per record.

AWS provides an example for [integrating API gateway with S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html).

Comment: "so rather than 1 "file" as you put it with 2 records in there, you have an object per record." Does that mean if i have 100 POST request, i will have 100 objects stored in S3? Then the next time, I do a DELETE request on 50 of the records there, then 50 of the objects stored in S3 will be deleted?

Comment: In general, yes.  When you store an object in S3, you provide a unique key and you use that unique key to manage it further, i.e. overwrite it, delete it, read it, etc.  It's a powerful general purpose (object) storage service that has alot of features.  Read up on it.

Answer (score 0):

One use case of DynamoDB is to use it as a pure key-value store.  For instance, you could use create a simple Wiki and store the documents, using the name of the document as the key.

There isn't a fundamental reason you couldn't use S3 for the same use case.  S3 is an object store, which is another way of storing objects given an individual key.

So, if your solution isn't doing complicated queries in dynamo using filter expressions, or other logic, you can probably just change the store, and treat each key/value pair as an S3 item stored with the key name.

There are some big caveats here.  Not the least of which is you'll probably run into S3's eventual consistent nature sooner or later if you're updating data, or even looking to see if a key exists before using it.  It's nearly impossible to tell if S3 or Dynamo is a better fit for your application's needs given the details provided.

The bigger question:  Why are you changing data stores?  If you have problems with Dynamo, it's best to ask about this problems.  There very well could be solutions.

Comment: thanks for sharing your knowledge, to answer your question, the reason why he wants to change the data store is because he said "dynamodb is more cost effective, thats why we are moving to s3"

Comment: I assume you mean "s3 is more cost effective".  While that may be true for storage costs, all bets are off if you're making millions of read and write requests, since you'll start running into S3 API costs.

Comment: nope you heard me right "dynamodb is more cost effective, thats why we are moving to s3" thats why i dont understand how is he the tech lead

Comment: At this point, I suspect you have questions more fitting for https://workplace.stackexchange.com =)